# large php script slowing down the rest of application.... why?

Tags: php

I have a large php web scraping script that logs the results onto a mysql database as it goes.The script generally runs for 5 to 10 minutes at a time.

The problem is that when this script is running other pages on the application will not load.

The script is on a dedicated server with plenty of RAM so I have tried increasing the allowed memory usage for MYSQL and PHP. Also increased the max allowed connections. None of this has helped.

Does anyone have any ideas about what else I can try?

Comment: Is your network connection saturated? Is your CPU maxed out?

Comment: Does the script use the same tables as the rest of the app?

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM engine on your DB? Row level locks v.s. table level locks. huge difference.

Comment: - I'm not sure if my CPU is maxed out, how would I go about finding this out?

Comment: run `top` from the command line.

Comment: It does use the same tables

Comment: I just checked top from the command line and nothing stood out. mySQL showed  CPU 0.3%  MEM 5.7%

Comment: Thanks guys... Seventoes comment led me to check network saturation which I think may have been the problem. When I use the app on another computer it works fine. Something to do with local limitations rather than on the server I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, problem in your session. Try to use session_write_close() before you start "big script".

Comment: Thanks @maxim, this is a really useful thing to understand - it was  relevant for me when running multiple php scripts from ajax calls. They were queuing up, now they're running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

well, there's a big difference between "slowing down" and "not load"!

try the following:

1. build a static html site and check if it is loaded well during the execution of the big script
2. build a php site that doesn't connect to the DB (just echo something) during the execution of the big script
3. build a small php site that connects to the DB (just select something from a table)

if 1 or 2 doesn't work well, your problem has something todo with the web server or server resources. if 3 doesn't work well, there could be resource issues with the mysql server.

if everything works well, check the scraping script. does it lock any table that is needed by the main application?

Comment: Your last question was answered in the comments, as the Engine is InnoDB, this means the engine only performs row level locks, as opposed to table level locks that occur in MyISAM.